# "I" hotkey for key frame in pose mode not working

Tags: keyframes, shortcut, pose-mode

Blender 2.8

I am not sure if I mishit a command or something.  But, the option menu for inserting keyframes such as location, rotation, etc do not appear when I hit "I" in pose mode.  However, hitting "I" in object mode works.

I have tried different blender files, and the same thing happen.

What gives?  How can I fix it?

thx

update May 29, 2020

Since nobody seems to know how to proceed.  I would like to share a blender file.  In this file, I try to hit "I" to insert keyframes in pose mode.  but the keyframes menu will not pop up.  How can I fix this?

[image]

PS. I reinstall the blender already.

(dont know if I m following the proper procedure on updating question here or not.  If not, let me know.  So I can rectify.  Thank you.)

Comment: have you selected a bone?

Comment: ya, I was animating my char.

Comment: It is working for me. You could reset your keymap. Keymaps persist over reinstalls.

Comment: I actually did restore factory setting to blender file and it works.. but I would like to try to change to 2.79 inputs.. but cant find an option to do it in user preference...